# What's the difference between RewriteRule and redirect 301

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I was using something like this...

```
RewriteRule here/(.*) http://www.there.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but couldn't get it to work

So I used this...

```
redirect 301 /here http://www.there.com
```

and it worked fine.

Can someone explain the difference?
Do you need both?

Also... how do I exclude paths from the redirect?

Like... 
redirect 301 all...

```
redirect 301 /here http://www.there.com
```

but

```
/here/stayhere.html
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with regex?

Comment: Yes... idealmachine below said it uses regex. Isn't that how everything is matched?

Comment: And Gumbo says it uses "regular expression"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[RewriteRule is handled by Apache's mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), while [Redirect is handled by mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). No, you don't need both.

Your RewriteRule (which uses regex) will not match `/here` (but will match such paths as `/here/foo.html`) because it is looking for a slash immediately after. You can make that optional by using a question mark:

```
RewriteRule ^here(/?.*) http://www.there.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now that will have the same effect as your Redirect. RewriteCond can be added to exclude certain paths:

```
RewriteCond $0 !/here/stayhere\.html
```

Note that some servers do not have mod_rewrite turned on by default. If adding `RewriteEngine on` to your configuration does not fix the problem and you cannot switch mod_rewrite on, at least mod_alias provides the RedirectMatch directive, which may be good enough:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/here(?!/stayhere\.html)(/?.*) http://www.there.com$1
```

Comment: redirect substitutes the match with the target, leaving the other parts intact. RewriteRule actually goes to the target entirely with nothing carried over from the searched portion. Big difference.

Comment: Your links don't work anymore.

Answer (score 4):

`Redirect` matches path prefixes. The following `Redirect` matches any path that’s prefix (path segment wise) is `/here` and appends it to the new URI:

```
Redirect 301 /here http://example.com
```

So any request whose path begins with `/here` will be redirected to `http://example.com` wile appending any following path suffixes of `/here` to `http://example.com`.

In contrast, `RewriteRule` works with regular expressions. In this case, the following `RewriteRule` will match any path that contains `here/`:

```
RewriteRule here/(.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Anything after `here/` will be appended to the new URL.

While both directives would have the same effect when requesting URLs with paths that begin with `/here`, `rewriterule` will also match any request that’s path just contains `here/` like `/not/here/foo`.

Furthermore, you can only use additional conditions with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond $0 !=here/stayhere.html
RewriteRule ^here(/.*)?$ http://example.com$0 [L,R=301]
```

If you would want to do the same with mod_alias, you will need to use `RedirectMatch` with a regular expression that will match anything but `/here/stayhere.html`.

Answer (score 1):

The RewriteRule probably didn't work because you're saying a slightly different thing than you were in the redirect. The RewriteRule requires the address to include the word "here", followed by a slash. The redirect requires the address to have the word "here" *preceded* by a slash. I would go with something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^here/?(.*) http://www.there.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The added `?` makes the slash optional, and the `^` at the beginning makes it so that the "here" has to be at the *start* of the address, not anywhere inside it.

As for excluding a particular address, you'd want to do that by preceding the RewriteRule with this line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(here/stayhere\.html)
```

That tells it to ignore the rule if they're asking for that address specifically.